# Xorg not running on Radeon RX Vega 7 on NixOS

Tags: xorg, nixos

The CPU is a Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon RX Vega 7 graphics.

NixOS has been installed. Boot media is still available.

X.0.log shows that it can't find a display.

It is difficult to get the logs off the machine but I will be happy to get as many as possible in the morning.

Appreciate any help despite the lack of information, this sort of issue is out of my area of knowledge.

Attaching the continence of config.nix and hw-config.nix:

```
# Edit this configuration file to define what should be installed on
# your system.  Help is available in the configuration.nix(5) man page
# and in the NixOS manual (accessible by running ‘nixos-help’).

{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ];

  # Use the systemd-boot EFI boot loader.
  boot.loader.systemd-boot.enable = true;
  boot.loader.efi.canTouchEfiVariables = true;

  networking.hostName = "MrNixosLaptop"; # Define your hostname.
  # networking.wireless.enable = true;  # Enables wireless support via wpa_supplicant.
  networking.networkmanager.enable = true;

  # Set your time zone.
  time.timeZone = "Australia/Brisbane";

  # The global useDHCP flag is deprecated, therefore explicitly set to false here.
  # Per-interface useDHCP will be mandatory in the future, so this generated config
  # replicates the default behaviour.
  networking.useDHCP = false;
  networking.interfaces.wlp2s0.useDHCP = true;

  # Configure network proxy if necessary
  # networking.proxy.default = "http://user:password@proxy:port/";
  # networking.proxy.noProxy = "127.0.0.1,localhost,internal.domain";

  # Select internationalisation properties.
  # i18n.defaultLocale = "en_US.UTF-8";
  # console = {
  #   font = "Lat2-Terminus16";
  #   keyMap = "us";
  # };

  # Enable the Plasma 5 Desktop Environment.
  services.xserver.enable = true;
  services.xserver.windowManager.leftwm.enable = true;
  # services.xserver.displayManager.sddm.enable = true;
  # services.xserver.desktopManager.plasma5.enable = true;
  

  # Configure keymap in X11
  # services.xserver.layout = "us";
  # services.xserver.xkbOptions = "eurosign:e";

  # Enable CUPS to print documents.
  # services.printing.enable = true;

  # Enable sound.
  sound.enable = true;
  hardware.pulseaudio.enable = true;

  # Enable touchpad support (enabled default in most desktopManager).
  services.xserver.libinput.enable = true;

  # Define a user account. Don't forget to set a password with ‘passwd’.
  users.users.daxx367 = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    extraGroups = [ "wheel" ]; # Enable ‘sudo’ for the user.
  };

  # List packages installed in system profile. To search, run:
  # $ nix search wget
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    wget
    vim
    firefox
    networkmanager
  ];

  # Some programs need SUID wrappers, can be configured further or are
  # started in user sessions.
  # programs.mtr.enable = true;
  # programs.gnupg.agent = {
  #   enable = true;
  #   enableSSHSupport = true;
  # };

  # List services that you want to enable:

  # Enable the OpenSSH daemon.
  # services.openssh.enable = true;

  # Open ports in the firewall.
  # networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ ... ];
  # networking.firewall.allowedUDPPorts = [ ... ];
  # Or disable the firewall altogether.
  # networking.firewall.enable = false;

  # This value determines the NixOS release from which the default
  # settings for stateful data, like file locations and database versions
  # on your system were taken. It‘s perfectly fine and recommended to leave
  # this value at the release version of the first install of this system.
  # Before changing this value read the documentation for this option
  # (e.g. man configuration.nix or on https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html).
  system.stateVersion = "20.09"; # Did you read the comment?

}
```

```
# Do not modify this file!  It was generated by ‘nixos-generate-config’
# and may be overwritten by future invocations.  Please make changes
# to /etc/nixos/configuration.nix instead.
{ config, lib, pkgs, modulesPath, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ (modulesPath + "/installer/scan/not-detected.nix")
    ];

  boot.initrd.availableKernelModules = [ "nvme" "xhci_pci" "ahci" "usb_storage" "sd_mod" "rtsx_pci_sdmmc" ];
  boot.initrd.kernelModules = [ ];
  boot.kernelModules = [ "kvm-amd" ];
  boot.extraModulePackages = [ ];

  fileSystems."/" =
    { device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/6caa67f7-3893-4a36-ac2c-ea841edfa25a";
      fsType = "ext4";
    };

  fileSystems."/boot" =
    { device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/1D27-EC4B";
      fsType = "vfat";
    };

  swapDevices =
    [ { device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/320bd3ad-b4c8-4d4a-812e-e6de23c5393a"; }
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it with the help of Gytis on the the Nix discord.

I added this to my config.nix:

```
 hardware = {
    enableRedistributableFirmware = true;
    enableAllFirmware = true;
    opengl = {
      enable = true;
      driSupport32Bit = config.hardware.opengl.enable;
    };
};
```

That didn't work so then I added this, but I didn't remove the above so it might be important.

```
boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_latest;
```

Good luck to anyone with this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with setting up X (or Wayland) on Slimbook Pro X 15 with AMD Radeon Graphics Vega 7 until I realized it requires Kernel > 5.5. They actually mention it in the specs. Now it's working like a charm!